# Why android.Matrix.setRotateM returns a matrix whose rotation direction is the opposite of the expected rotation matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, rotation, glsl

For example, if I give the following parameters:

```
float[] rotateMatrix = identityMatrix.clone();
Matrix.setRotateM(rotateMatrix, 0, 90, 0, 0, 1);
```

I expect a matrix which rotates 90 degrees counter clockwise, which should be:

```
0       -1.0     
1.0    0
```

but actually the returned rotateMatrix is:

```
0       1.0    
-1.0    0
```

And curiously, the rendered output is correct, the image is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise(rather than clockwise). Why?

Comment: Is it because the returned matrix is column major order and thus I interpreted it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because OpenGL (ES) matrices are specified by vectors in column major order.

See [`android.opengl.Matrix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix):

> Matrix math utilities. These methods operate on **OpenGL ES format matrices** and vectors stored in float arrays.
>
> Matrices are 4 x 4 column-vector matrices stored in column-major order:
>
> ```
> m[offset +  0] m[offset +  4] m[offset +  8] m[offset + 12]
> m[offset +  1] m[offset +  5] m[offset +  9] m[offset + 13]
> m[offset +  2] m[offset +  6] m[offset + 10] m[offset + 14]
> m[offset +  3] m[offset +  7] m[offset + 11] m[offset + 15]
> ```

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf#page=111&zoom=100,0,280), page 110:

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in column-major order
>   .
>
> ```c
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>      float, float, float, float,  // second column
>      float, float, float, float,  // third column
>      float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

So a GLSL `mat4` can be set by the 4 vectors for the axis and the translation:

```c
mat4 m44 = mat4(
    vec4( Xx, Xy, Xz, 0.0),
    vec4( Yx, Xy, Yz, 0.0),
    vec4( Zx  Zy  Zz, 0.0),
    vec4( Tx, Ty, Tz, 1.0) );
```

After a mathematical rotation to the right (counter clockwise) around the z-axis *(0, 0, 1)*, the x axis is *(0, 1, 0)* and the y-axis is *(-1, 0, 0)*, which leads to the matrix:

```
 0  1  0  0   // x axis vector
-1  0  0  0   // y axis vector
 0  0  1  0   // z axis vector
 0  0  0  1   // translation vector
```